# I don't want the code to work when delete button on the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I want to deactivate the code below when the delete button is clicked.

I want to show the value entered in textfield as (XXX) XXX XXXX but when delete button is clicked, it is not deleted due to the insert.

How can I do this?

my code:

```
extension CreateOrEditVC:UITextFieldDelegate{
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


        if number.text!.count == 1 {
            number.text!.insert("(", at: number.text!.startIndex)
        }

        if number.text!.count == 4 {
            number.text!.insert(")", at: number.text!.index(number.text!.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))
        }

        if number.text!.count == 5 {
            number.text!.insert(" ", at: number.text!.index(number.text!.startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
        }

        if number.text!.count == 9 {
            number.text!.insert(" ", at: number.text!.index(number.text!.startIndex, offsetBy: 9))
        }


        guard let textFieldText = number.text, let rangeOfTextToReplace = Range(range, in: textFieldText) else {
                return false
        }

        let substringToReplace = textFieldText[rangeOfTextToReplace]
        let count = textFieldText.count - substringToReplace.count + string.count
        return count <= 14
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//there is a param 'replacementString string'
if string == "" {
   //delete
   return true
}
```